# Sender email is strange in gmail interface while using Gmail API

Tags: go, gmail-api

I use method of `google.golang.org/api/gmail/v1` for sending messages with "me" `userId`:

```
gm, err := gmail.NewUsersMessagesService(service).Send("me", gm).Do()
    if err != nil {
        return
    }
```

Let's say, my email address is `myemail@gmail.com`. I expect that recipient will get my message with my email (or Name + Surname) in `From` field. However, in gmail interface it's showed as `myemail`. 
The same situation when I set email manually.

Could you please help me to figure out a proper signature for this API method to make sender name previewed as Name + Surname or as a full email?

Comment: The `SendAs` type may be helpful. https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/api/gmail/v1#SendAs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build your message in this way to achieve what you desire:

```
    user := "me"
    full_name := "John Doe"
    email := "myexample@gmail.com"

    // New message for our gmail service to send
    var message gmail.Message

    // Compose the message
    messageStr := []byte(
        "From: " + full_name + "<" + email + ">" + "\r\n" +
            "To: sendto@gmail.com\r\n" +
            "Subject: My first Gmail API message\r\n\r\n" +
            "Message body goes here!")

    // Place messageStr into message.Raw in base64 encoded format
    message.Raw = base64.URLEncoding.EncodeToString(messageStr)

    // Send the message
    _, err = service.Users.Messages.Send(user, &message).Do()
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("Error: %v", err)
    } else {
        fmt.Println("Message sent!")
    }
```

This is due to the API must check the headers from the email and if it doesn't recognize the headers in the right way it will use the default one like for example ***from: myexample***.

[HERE](https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/api/gmail/v1) you can check more about the Go's Gmail package.